# ¿Como conectarse con BDD de servidor en Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Buenas, mi problema es que necesito conectarme a la base de datos que tengo en un servidor. El server lo tengo de "Hostinger", es gratuito pero para la capacidad que da solo es para pocas cosas como para una BDD.

La cosa es que estoy programando con esa bdd en eclipse (lenguaje java) y estoy usando hibernate para las vistas, codigo y demas. Por ahora me va bien porque tengo la bdd en local pero ahora que lo subi quiero conectarme para ver si va.

Uso este codigo para la conexion en Hibernate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
     root</property>                              //contraseña

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
     jdbc:mysql://localhost/comunidad</property>  //nombre bdd

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">  //usuario
     root</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

    <mapping class="es.sdos.bean.Paciente"/>
    <mapping class="es.sdos.bean.Usuario"/>
    <mapping class="es.sdos.bean.Actividad"/>
</session-factory>
```

Alli estoy especificando la version del msql, usu, pass, nombre bdd, esos datos son de las bdd local.

Ahora estos son los datos que me da la bdd del servidor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se veria asi con esos datos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
     u137181788_altair</property>             //cambie la contraseña(altair)

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
     jdbc:mysql://mysql.hostinger.es/u137181788_bdd</property>  //nombre bdd

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">  //usuario
     u137181788_root</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

    <mapping class="es.sdos.bean.Paciente"/>
    <mapping class="es.sdos.bean.Usuario"/>
    <mapping class="es.sdos.bean.Actividad"/>
</session-factory>
```

Solo cambie el nombre de la bdd de "comunidad" a "bdd" y la contraseña de "root" a "altair".
Probe con el codigo que se pospone y sin el: "u137181788_"root

fallos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema parece que está en el nombre del host. La excepción te está diciendo que no es capaz de encontrar `mysql.hostinger.es`.

En el [foro de soporte](https://www.hostinger.es/forum/ayuda-con-php-y-mysql/136-conectarme-a-base-de-datos.html) de Hostinger indican que las bases de datos tienen las conexiones externas restringidas, solo se puede acceder a ellas desde un servidor de su dominio. Si intentas llegar al host desde un navegador, o por ping, la conexión falla, ese dominio no está registrado en los DNS públicos, seguramente solo exista en su DNS interno.

Si estás tratando de acceder desde tu entorno de desarrollo, ese es el problema. Debería funcionar si tienes tu aplicación desplegada en sus servidores.